Http Only cookies in node express with JWT and react frontend
I have a node express server which use JWT for auth. I originally just added the token in local storage in my frontend, but have now tried to implement HTTP only cookies.
My server is hosted on heroku while my react.js frontend is hosted on netlify.
I have set up CORS correctly and added the res.cookie in thee auth route with httponly: true, secure: true, samesite: None
In my frontend I am using fetch with credentials: 'include'
The JWT token will not be created. error in heroku log: Error creating JWT token: TypeError: option sameSite is invalid
If i set sameSite: lax or strict the jwt token is sent to the browser, but it will not send it back to the server to fetch my /users for example.
App.js
app.set("trust proxy", 1); // trust first proxy

const corsOptions = {
  origin: [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://localhost:3001",
    "http://localhost:3002",
    "https://techhype.netlify.app",
    "https://techhype.no",
    "https://techhype-server-06db1c82ee3e.herokuapp.com",
  ],
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

auth.js route
router.post("/login", authLimiter, jsonParser, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  if (email == null) {
    return res.jsend.fail({ statusCode: 400, email: "Email is required." });
  }
  if (password == null) {
    return res.jsend.fail({
      statusCode: 400,
      password: "Password is required.",
    });
  }

  // Retrieve the user by email
  const user = await userService.getOneByEmail(email);
  if (!user) {
    return res.jsend.fail({
      statusCode: 400,
      result: "Incorrect email or password",
    });
  }

  // Check if the user is verified
  if (!user.Verified) {
    return res.jsend.fail({
      statusCode: 400,
      result: "User is not verified. Please check your email for the verification link.",
    });
  }

  // Verify the password
  crypto.pbkdf2(password, user.Salt, 310000, 32, "sha256", function (err, hashedPassword) {
    if (err) {
      return res.jsend.error("Error in password encryption");
    }
    if (!crypto.timingSafeEqual(user.EncryptedPassword, hashedPassword)) {
      return res.jsend.fail({ result: "Incorrect password" });
    }

    try {
      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
          id: user.id,
          email: user.Email,
          role: user.Role,
          Verified: user.Verified,
          name: user.FirstName,
        },
        process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION }  // or "3600" (expressed in seconds)
      );

      const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
        { id: user.id },
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION_LONG }  // or "604800" (expressed in seconds)
      );

      console.log("Token creation: ", token);

      // Set the JWT and refresh token in HTTP-only cookies
      res.cookie('token', token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true, //true in production only
        sameSite: 'None', // can be 'strict' or 'lax or None',
      });
      res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'None',
      });

      return res.jsend.success({
        result: "You are logged in",
        id: user.id,
        email: user.Email,
        name: user.FirstName,
        role: user.Role,
        verified: user.Verified
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error creating JWT token:", err);
      return res.jsend.error("Something went wrong with creating the JWT token");
    }
  });
});

isAuth middleware
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

// Middleware function to determine if the API endpoint request is from an authenticated user
function isAuth(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.cookies.token;
  console.log("Received Token:", token); // Log the received token
  if (token) {
    try {
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
      req.user = decodedToken; // Attach user data to the request object
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401).json({ status: "fail", statusCode: 401, error: "Authentication failed" });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ status: "fail", statusCode: 401, error: "No token provided" });
  }
}

module.exports = isAuth;

Fetch users in react frontend
   const fetchUserData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/users`, {
                method: 'GET',
                credentials: 'include', // Ensure cookies are included
            });
            const data = await response.json(); // Always parse JSON to check for error details
            console.log("user data response:", data);
            
            if (response.ok) {
                updateUser(data.data.result.user);
            } else {
                console.error('Failed to fetch user data', data);
                throw new Error(data.message || 'Failed to fetch user data');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Fetch user data error:', error);
        }
    };
    

